# SQL Pivot on subset

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have the following result set:

> Type | Method | Amount
>
> Type1 Cash Amount
>   Type1 Check Amount
>  
>   Type2 Cash Amount
>  
>   Type2 Check Amount
>  
>   Type3 Cash Amount
>   Type3 Check Amount

And I want to make it look like this:

> Type | Cash | Check
>
> Type1 Amount Amount
>   Type2 Amount Amount
>   Type3 Amount Amount

How can I achieve this in  T-SQL (2005 syntax ok)? I need to pivot by type (1, 2, 3...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt at PIVOT:

```
select *
from YourTable
PIVOT (sum(amount) FOR Method in (Cash,Check)) as Y
```

Given that it's just two columns, could try with a join:

```
select
    type
,   cash = a.amount
,   check = b.amount
from yourtable a
full join yourtable b on a.type = b.type
where a.method = 'cash' or b.method = 'Check'
```

Comment: Thanks. There are other columns - this is just an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet:

```
select
  Type
, Cash  = sum(case when Method = 'Cash'  then Amount end)
, Check = sum(case when Method = 'Check' then Amount end) 
from yourtable
group by 
  Type
```

Add an ELSE 0 to the CASE statements if appropriate.

This form is more flexible than the PIVOT operator and doesn't require a FULL JOIN. Just straight aggregation.